# RecyclerView destroys after fragment transaction

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, fragmenttransaction

I have a base activity and a fragment with list of items. When a user taps an item in list, a fragment transaction starts and current fragment with recycler view is being added to back stack and replaced with other fragment. But, after returning back, it destroys recycler view and reloads it. How can i prevent recycler view from destroying?

**EDIT**

I've got recycler view subclass -

```
public class AppListView extends RecyclerView {

private LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager;

public boolean isParent() {
    return isParent;
}

public void setParent(boolean isParent) {
    this.isParent = isParent;
}

private boolean isParent = false;

public AppListView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public AppListView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public AppListView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent e) {
    int startScrollState = getScrollState();
    if (e.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN && startScrollState == SCROLL_STATE_SETTLING) {
        stopScroll();
    }
    boolean result = super.onInterceptTouchEvent(e);
    return result;
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent e) {
    boolean result = super.onTouchEvent(e);
    return result;
}

public LinearLayoutManager getLinearLayoutManager() {
    return linearLayoutManager;
}

public void setLinearLayoutManager(LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager) {
    setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
    this.linearLayoutManager = linearLayoutManager;
}

}
```

And adding it to fragment here :

```
    @Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    setRetainInstance(isRetainInstance());
    if (!isSignedUpEventBus) {
        getEventBus().register(this);
        isSignedUpEventBus = true;
    }
    setViews();
    setActions();
}
```

adding like this :

```
    @Override
protected void setViews() {
    listH = 0;
    list = (AppListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.list);
    layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getBaseActivity());
    layoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    list.setLinearLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    list.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(
            new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

                @Override
                public void onGlobalLayout() {
                    listH = list.getHeight();
                    listW = list.getWidth();
                    initData();
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 16) {
                        list.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
                    } else {
                        list.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
                    }
                }
            });
    list.setParent(true);

}
```

Comment: Could you please post your code? How are you initializing the recyclerview?

Comment: The onCreateView method is being invoked when the Fragment comes back into view. That's most likely where you instantiate an instance of your RecylcerView. You need to pass it a Bundle savedInstanceState for it to remember it's position

Comment: @chRyNaN - but it would be removed from screen? and the user will see a blank view for a moment?

Comment: Try to call `add()` instead of `replace()`.

Comment: No. Your RecylcerView will be created normally within the onCreateView and passed the instance state right after. There should be no noticeable lapse.

Comment: Malwinder. Incorrect. Calling add performs a different function calling Replace and is not relevant to this. @Nikita, please ignore that comment. It will not help you.

Comment: @NikitaPronchik did you find a solution?